# Methods to pass custom object from one page to another in asp.net webform

Tags: asp.net

I want to pass a custom object from one page to another in C# asp.net> As far as I knwo the following are the availabel methods:

1. a public property in the PreviousPage (if the navigation happened through Server.Transfer)
2. Session
3. Cookie
4. As Form Controls (if the page doesn't have a master page.)
5. Querystring (Not suitable for custom objects)

Is there any alternate method? I can't use any of these due to various reasons.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As far as passing the custom object one alternative would be using jQuery to call a web service from the onclick event of the link on page A and the $(document).ready function (or page load method) on page B and passing a JSON serialized object out and back.

For this to work, however, you still have to some way of identifying the user on page B so you can get the correct object for that user that was saved from page A.  If you can use Session, Cookie or QueryString to pass a guid or some other unique identifier, you're all set.  If not, I think you've ruled out all your options, and you'll need to give more details about how you are authenticating your user, what your needed security is for the site and from page to page.